# When Event Handler code is executed in a background thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, event-handling, desktop-application

I am reading [an article](https://johnthiriet.com/configure-await/#) right now that says

> "... most of the time the completion method would be invoked in a
>   background thread."

If I correctly understood, the author says that in UI-application Event Handler code **could be** executed in a background thread. And, if so, who decides where Event Handler code will execute in UI thread or background thread? Maybe it is just specific of .NET desktop application?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the code presented and reading the whole sentence. The sentence starts: “The problem with **this approach** is...” And the article goes on to explain how things should be done instead of using that approach. It’s executed in another thread because the code invoking the event is in another thread.

Comment: It's a mix different informations. See: [It's All About the SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/magazine/gg598924.aspx). If an event is raised in a thread other than the UI thread, then the event, because of thread affinity, is of course not raised in the UI thread (why would it be?). A TPL Task can use the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`. With the `async/await` pattern, `await` captures the current SynchronizationContext (if there is one to capture). Events raised by UI controls are always executed in the UI thread (in a *standard* UI context).